# How to fetch the uploaded file path as response from rest-api call

Tags: reactjs

I have a reactjs page that uploads a file to server. The server is just a spring-boot app that hosts rest api to serve the upload. Once the file is uploaded, i want to return the absolute path of the uploaded file as part of my response. I am able to achieve that as well but the response body shows just ReadableStream when i console logged it. I am not getting the actual path of the file that am setting in spring before sending out the response.

I Have tried to set the response entity object with body containing the response json in string format.

React Code:

```
import React from 'react';
class UploadImage extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            uploadData:''
        }
        this.handleFileUpload=this.handleFileUpload.bind(this);
    }
    handleFileUpload=(event)=>{
        event.preventDefault();
        //alert('uploaded file')
        //console.log(this.uploadedFile.files[0]);
        const data = new FormData();
        data.append('uploadedFile',this.uploadedFile.files[0]);
        
        fetch('http://localhost:8080/laptops/upload',{
            method:'POST',
            body:data
        }).then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            console.log(response.json);
          });
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleFileUpload}>
                    <input type='file' ref={(ref)=>{this.uploadedFile=ref}}/>
                    <input type='submit' value='upload'/>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default UploadImage;
```

Boot code: (only look into the post mapping function)

```
package react.demo.app;

import oracle.jdbc.proxy.annotation.Post;
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
class Laptop{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String brand;
    private double price;
    private String image;
    public Laptop(){

    }
    public Laptop(String name,String brand,double price,String image){
        this.name=name;
        this.brand=brand;
        this.price=price;
        this.image=image;
    }
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }

    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
@Repository
interface LaptopRepository extends JpaRepository<Laptop,Long>{}

@Service
class LaptopService{
@Autowired
LaptopRepository laptopRepository;
public void addLaptop(Laptop laptop){
    laptopRepository.save(laptop);
}
public Laptop getLaptopById(long id){return laptopRepository.getOne(id); }
public List<Laptop> getAllLaptops(){
    return laptopRepository.findAll();
}
}
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/laptops")
class LaptopApi{
    @Autowired LaptopService laptopService;
    private String uploadDir = "C:\\Users\\rajen\\Development\\upload_images\\";
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
    @GetMapping(value="/",produces="application/json")
    public List<Laptop> getAllLaptops(){
        return laptopService.getAllLaptops();
    }
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
    @PostMapping(value = "/upload")
    public ResponseEntity upload(@RequestParam("uploadedFile") MultipartFile uploadedFile) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("invoked upload");
        File f = new File(uploadDir+uploadedFile.getOriginalFilename());
        uploadedFile.transferTo(f);
        System.out.println("return uploaded file:"+f.toURI());
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(responseHeaders).body("{uploadedfile:"+f.getAbsolutePath()+"}");
    }
    @GetMapping(value="/getLaptopById",produces="application/json")
    public Laptop getLaptopById(@RequestParam long id){
        System.out.println("laptop by id:"+id);
        return laptopService.getLaptopById(id);
    }
    @PostMapping(value="/addLaptop")
    public void addLaptop(@RequestBody Laptop laptop){
        laptopService.addLaptop(laptop);
    }

}
@SpringBootApplication
public class AppApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired LaptopService laptopService;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(AppApplication.class,args);
    }
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Laptop laptop = new Laptop("Dell Inspiron","Dell",new Double(25990),"https://i.pinimg.com/564x/4a/bb/86/4abb8659d4d951a6fefefe401a02aeb7.jpg");
        laptopService.addLaptop(laptop);
        System.out.println("Laptop Added");
    }

}
```

i expect to see the file path as part of the response body but am getting only Readablestream as the body.

[Refer to console log here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykGBZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are receiving a json payload, you need to call the .json() method method on the promise to extract the body data, and return that value (as opposed to just .json, an attempt to access property on the response). Alternatively, if the body data is simply text -- which it may be given the value you are attempting to return, you may need to call the .text() method.

```
      fetch('http://localhost:8080/laptops/upload', {
            method:'POST',
            body:data
          }).then((response) => {
             return response.json();
          }).then(finalRes => console.log(finalRes))
         .catch(e)
    }
```